# Refer vue.js data but nothing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

1.I am a beginner of vue.js, but when I was trying some examples, I found something uncommon. The first one is when I set `id` in the `body`, and write my js code as followed:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/semantic.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vue.js">
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;" id="app">
<div class="ui container" style="margin:20px;">
    <div class="ui segment">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <p>
            {{ message }}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            message: "Hello, world!",
            title: "How about you?"
        }
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my result which does not show me data :
[image: (I leave out the comments area code)]

---

2.And the second problem is when I created an object in the data, and I refer it as followed, it also does not work in the `div` label.
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/semantic.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vue.js">
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;">
<div class="ui container" style="margin:20px;">
    <div class="ui segment" id="app">
        <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
        <p>
            {{ article.message }}
        </p>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            article{
                message: "Hello, world!",
                title: "How about you?"
            }
        }
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I wonder if there some conflicts when I was using semanticUI and vue.js?

Comment: You cannot mount to the body in Vue. And you have a syntax error in your second example `article{` should be `article: {`. But also, if you have two questions it should really be in two separate posts. Please read the help page on [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As a best practice, you can create a top level div#app. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a best practice, you can create a top level `div#app`, like this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        message: "Hello, world!",
        title: "How about you?"
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color:black;">
<div id="app"><!-- just a wrapper for vuejs -->
  <div class="ui container" style="margin:20px;">
      <div class="ui segment">
          <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
          <p>
              {{ message }}
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: But if I add a ```div``` which is just for adding ```id```, this seems a little meaningless, is there a good alternative in the ```body``` label which could charge the whole ```body``` part, for vue.js1.0 could set in the ```body```.